# use specific lein-cljsbuild config in repl-launch?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, leiningen

Is there a way to specify only build a specific build configuration via repl-launch?

Maybe something like:

```
lein trampoline cljsbuild <build_config_id> repl-launch chrome
```

I'd like my :dev and :prod build configurations to output to the same file so that I don't have to worry about having an index-dev.html which includes cljsoutput-dev.js etc.

Currently I start my server with

```
lein ring server-headless 3000
```

Comment: Hi @Core, does my answer fit your problem now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can find the solution on the lein-cljsbuild repl-support  page, https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild/blob/1.0.1/doc/REPL.md#repl-launch

You can specify the repl-launch-commands as cljs-build properties

```
(defproject lein-cljsbuild-example "1.2.3"
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.0.1"]]
  :cljsbuild {
    :repl-listen-port 9000
    :repl-launch-commands
      {"my-launch" ["firefox" "-jsconsole" "http://localhost/my-page"]})
```

There is also a [@cemerick/austin](https://github.com/cemerick/austin) project very releated with this problematic that maybe can helps you too. ([Browser-connected REPLs](https://github.com/cemerick/austin#browser-connected-repls))